# Variable in CDATA in Scala

Tags: scala, cdata, scala-xml

Is there a way to put a variable to be expanded in a cdata section in scala

```
val reason = <reason><![CDATA[ {failedReason} ]]></reason>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not sure if you can get that through native XML support, but you could do something like:

```
scala.xml.XML.loadString("<reason><![CDATA[%s]]></reason>".format(failedReason))
```

You lose some of the compile-time validations that way, but it should give you am xml element with the data which you are looking for. Since it returns a `scala.xml.Elem`, you can also embed the result in a larger XML structure.

**EDIT**

After thinking about this a bit more, the following may be a beter (and less fragile) way to do this. It restricts the free-text portion to only the CDATA, minimizing the potential for unbalanced expressions.

```
<reason>{ scala.xml.Unparsed("<![CDATA[%s]]>".format(failedReason)) }</reason>
```

Answer (score 27):

It could be even simplier:

```
val reason = <reason>{scala.xml.PCData(failedReason)}</reason>
```

Comment: You might want to escape illegal `]]>`: `content.replaceAll("]]>", "]]]]><![CDATA[>")`

Comment: I'm not sure the comment by @BrunoBieth applies to this (great!) answer. It already correctly deals with "gotcha" strings:
`<reason>{scala.xml.PCData("]]>")}</reason>` becomes 
`<reason><![CDATA[]]]]><![CDATA[>]]></reason>`